# JavaScript Form Validation not working using isNaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have changed my code and added the isNaN to make sure a credit card validation is checking that only numbers are entered, however it broke the code.

Note this is only a code snippet of the broken code.
Tried adding backets and moving around code.

```js
    var american = document.getElementById("americanInput").value;
    var master = document.getElementById("masterInput").value;
    var visa = document.getElementById("visaInput").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var errMsg = document.getElementById("errMsg");
    var postcode = document.getElementById("billingPostcode").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("billingAddress").value;
    var suburb = document.getElementById("billingSuburb").value;
    } else if (master.length > 0 && master.length !== 16 && isNaN(master)||
        visa.length > 0 && visa.length !== 16 && isNaN(visa)||
        american.length > 0 && american.length !== 15 && isNaN(american)){
        errMsg.innerHTML = "Please check your card details again";
        return false;
    } else if (postcode.length < 4 || (!postcode.match(/^[0-9]*$/))) {
        errMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid postcode";
        return false;
    } else if (suburb.length < 8 || address.length < 8) {
        errMsg.innerHTML = "Please check your address, to confirm details"
        return false;
    }
```

The code should validate and give an error message.

Comment: can you show the values of the variables you tried and explain what you saw happen?

Comment: `isNaN` means `is not a number`; in this case, you should use `!isNaN(master)` to filter non-numeric values

Comment: Why not checking it on input with `type="number"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I have used 'OR' condition with isNaN instead of 'AND' condition. I assume you are checking for the credit card value is not null/undefined in your code. If not you need to check to make sure the below code works.

```
  var american = document.getElementById("americanInput").value;
  var master = document.getElementById("masterInput").value;
  var visa = document.getElementById("visaInput").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var errMsg = document.getElementById("errMsg");
  var postcode = document.getElementById("billingPostcode").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("billingAddress").value;
  var suburb = document.getElementById("billingSuburb").value;

  if ((master.length > 0 && (master.length !== 16 || isNaN(master))) || 
            (visa.length > 0 && (visa.length !== 16 || isNaN(visa))) || 
            (american.length > 0 && (american.length !== 15 || isNaN(american)))) {
      alert("Please check your card details again");
    return false;
  } else if (postcode.length < 4 || (!postcode.match(/^[0-9]*$/))) {
              alert("Please enter a valid postcode");
    return false;
  } else if (suburb.length < 8 || address.length < 8) {
          alert("Please check your address, to confirm details");
    return false;
  }
```